# how to display dependent drop-down in django form

Tags: django, ajax

Here while adding the student fee information from template if a user select some course then only this selected course's basic_price and advanced_price should displayed in the select fee option.How can i achieve this ?

student_fee.html

```
     <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Course <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
        <div class="controls">
         <select name="course" id="personForm" data-fees-url="{% url 'students:ajax_load_course_fees' %}" required class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Course</option>
                        {% for course in courses %}
        <option value="{{course.id}}">{{course.title}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
       </select>
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Total Fee <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
            <div class="controls">
             <select name="total_fee" id="select3" required class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select Fee</option>
            </select>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new function that will return the fees specific to a course, but called from ajax

```
def ajax_course_fees(request):
    course = Course.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('course_pk'))
    #generate an html template for the specific option
    return render(request, 'fees_dropdown_list_options.html', {'course': course})
```

the associate template:

fees_dropdown_list_options.html

```
<option value="">Select Fee</option>
<option value="{{course.basic_price}}">{{course.basic_price}}(Basic)</option>
<option value="{{course.advanced_price}}">{{course.advanced_price}}(Advanced)</option>
```

In urls.py add this:

```
 path('ajax/load-course-fees/', views.ajax_course_fees, name='ajax_load_course_fees'),
```

In your template you need to remove the fees by default, they will be dynamically loaded from ajax call for each Course

And I provide the Jquery to make the ajax call.

```
<select name="course" id="select2" data-fees-url="{% url 'ajax_load_course_fees' %}" required class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Course</option>
        {% for course in courses %}
            <option value="{{course.id}}">{{course.title}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
<select name="total_fee" id="select3" required class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Fee</option>
</select>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#select2").change(function () {
      var url = $("#select2").attr("data-fees-url");  // get the url of the ajax_load_course_fees view
      var course_pk = $(this).val();  // get the selected course pk from the HTML input

      $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request
        data: {
          'course_pk': course_pk       // add the course pk to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `ajax_course_fees` view function
          $("#select3").html(data);  // replace the contents of the fees select with the data that came from the server
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

And for you information: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: Their was one error in the ajax call(didnt select the url from select2). Now you should be abble to see the fees for each course. Can you show me the error? With value you just get the value of that field. But you dont know if its valid or sanatized

Comment: yes i already noticed that error  and now  the code is working fine.Thank you so much

Comment: Look at the view I gave you. Cleaned data are only available after form.is_valid.